# Compiler error 3921

Tags: .net, xml, visual-c++

I am following  a tutorial on Function x http://www.functionx.com/vcnet/xml/readwrite.htm. I have got as far as the first step adding everything to the forms and started to implement the 'reset order event'. The compiler is now coming up with 46 cases or error 3921. If anyone could help me out I would be extremely grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide us with the exact error message?

Comment: Sorted it, I think. I deleted the S before the variable i.e  this->txtPartUnitPrice5->Text = ***S***"0.00";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use of S-prefixed strings requires /clr:oldSyntax command line option

Delete the S prefix.